# Azure B2C Custom Policy - Write custom attribute value from token in user journey

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I have deployed a custom policy like in the following doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-api-connector?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

I call a rest api and it returns custom attribute value in token. How can I write the value to the custom attribute from token in user journey?

I want to save the returned value in users custom attribute, not only to pass it to application via token.

I didn't find any fitting samples or info from documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the API, map like:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_attribute PartnerClaimType="API value" />
```

and then add the extension attribute as an output to one of the "AAD-UserWriteUsingxxx" methods that you can add to the user journey.